# MVC for desktop app with no data layer

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, genetic-algorithm

Question might be tricky (because of its nature or my way of describing it), so really read this before answering.

I have this app to write:
a) desktop app;
b) no data layer in sense of database, files or any other repository (no need to save, store or load data);
c) app will have some computation algorithms implemented (Genetic Algorithm);
b) provides GUI which will display controls for app and computations results.

I am thinking about using MVC pattern but I have doubts how to use it. Since I have no data layer in sense of (for example) database (data is generated during execution based on user input) I am concerned about way of using MVC in this implementation. So far I have came up with two approaches:

1. GUI is the View. GeneticAlgorithm is the Controller. GeneticAlgorithmResults is the Model (as class that only stores data). Basic flow:

   - The View sends user input to the Controller;
   - The Controller is processing user input and generates data;
   - The Controller sends generated data to the Model;
   - The Model notifies the View about new data;
   - The View pulls new Data and updates the display.
2. GUI is the View. AppEngine is the Controller. GeneticAlgorithm nad GeneticAlgorithmResults are the Model. Now we have:

   - The View sends user input to the Controller;
   - The Controller is processing user input and sends control signals to the Model.
   - The Model updates its internal state (generates new data);
   - The Model notifies the Controller about new data;
   - The Controller pulls data to model;
   - The Controller processes data;
   - The controller pushes processed data to the View;
   - The View updates the display.

First approach seems to be more straightforward and more like MVC. The problem is that some logic would have to be in the Model - decide when to notify the model as not all data updates will be displayed, or maybe display will be updated with the sets of data not every little change. Those decisions will be based on user input. Whats more some additional processing of the data may be needed before actual display. This would be in the View.

On the other hand second approach seems to be more complicated and looks like to much messages are being passed to achieve the task. But it gives full control of Logic to the Controller and separates responsibilities of the View, the Controller and the Model (which is the main purpose of MVC).

Which approach would you recommend? Or maybe I should mix them and use first approach architecture with communication flow from second approach? Or some different design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of MVC, the second version is more like the strict MVC paradigm. However, one of my very intelligent teachers once told me that the design patterns are there to give a loose set of guidelines and are not necessarily meant to be followed to the T.

In my opinion, a mix of both is a good idea. If some logic ends up in the Model, it isn't the end of the world, it just means that you have to be more careful about keeping track of the separation of your components. If a small modification to MVC makes your life 50% easier (less message overhead), then it is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with something closer to the second implementation.  Yes, it does seem like more messages passed back and forth, but if your application grows and changes, you will be happy that you've built the application with small classes.

Consider: Where is the logic to handle mundane tasks like switching between algorithms, executing them and processing the data for viewing?

Genetic algorithms operate on some kind of input or starting data, don't they?  You would get this from your data access layer.  Don't you need seed data or initialization conditions?  What about saving your results to file and retrieving them for review later?  I would think that you need to do this once your application matures.  Expect that at first you will use file based persistence.  If you're feeling up to it, later you can upgrade to a database.  If you code against an abstracted data persistence layer, you won't have to change business logic later to support the change from file to database.

You should use the strategy pattern to implement your algorithms.  This will allow you to change the implementation of your solver from genetic algorithm to your other algorithms without having to change the business logic for each algorithm.

The business layer will see a ISolver that takes inputs, and you will call mySolver.Solve().  You should be able to switch between the different versions without having to change your business layer logic ([Open Closed Principle](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/07/01/1875.aspx)).  The only difference in the way the business logic should interact with the algorithms should be in the constructor, and even there, you should consider using a Factory pattern.